# Children's novel where destroying computer's paper backup changes what planet humanity settled on

Tags: story-identification, space

Can you help me identify a children's novel, probably "juvenile" reading level.

The main character is a boy. Long after losing earth, humanity lives on a colony planet that is barely habitable because that is the best planet they could find. There is a prominent supercomputer on the planet. I think the supercomputer is central to the government, and that the government turns out to be evil. A major goal in the story is to shut down the computer, and burn the paper backups of its records. For reasons I don't remember, this changes the past so that humanity had settled on a different planet. One of the planets was a very hot desert planet and the other is an ice planet. In the last chapter, the boy wakes up in the new planet does not have the same social/government problems as the original one.

The tone was serious and dramatic.

I read this in English in the United States in the 1990s, but the computer technology made me pretty sure it was written in a previous decade.